# Get version number of my website

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

The website is an old aspx website.  We are running under C# 4.5 using Visual Studio 2013 if that helps.

My AssemblyInfo.cs file has the following in it.

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

I have taken out the AssemblyFileVersion attribute.

on my default.aspx file I have the following;

```
Site version: <%= System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString() %>
```

However the version that is displayed is always 0.0.0.0.

I have followed the sample on SO and also from http://abundantcode.com/how-to-get-auto-incrementing-version-number-in-visual-studio-2013/ but I still get 0.0.0.0

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How about: `typeof(yourMainClass).Assembly.GetName().Version`?

Comment: Hope you are using the top level class as your `yourMainClass`?

Comment: I am yes.  Even tried the mvc class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Try like this:

```
typeof(yourMainClass).Assembly.GetName().Version
```

---

You can try like this:

```
var str = HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance;
Assembly assem = str.GetType().BaseType.Assembly;
System.Version assemblyVersion = assem.GetName().Version;
```

or like this:

```
var ver = Assembly.GetAssembly(Page.GetType().BaseType).GetName().Version;
```

Comment: Actually, it just started working and the solution was your comment to my question.  Weird.

Comment: @griegs:- Updated my answer with the solution that worked for you!